# Show a list of dates between two dates?

Tags: mysql, database

How to show a list of date between between `start_date` and `end_date`?

I have tried using group by `group by DAY(start_date),DAY(end_date)` but no success.

For example, in the booking table it look like this:

```
+----+-----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| id | client_id | car_id | start_date          | end_date            | status   |
+----+-----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
|  1 |         1 |      2 | 2015-10-03 00:00:00 | 2015-10-05 00:00:00 | Reserved |
|  2 |         3 |      5 | 2015-10-15 00:00:00 | 2015-10-17 00:00:00 | Hired    |
+----+-----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I wanted the result to be like this:

```
client_id   car_id   booked_date   status
1             2      2015-10-03   Reserved
1             2      2015-10-04   Reserved
1             2      2015-10-05   Reserved
3             5      2015-10-15   Hired
3             5      2015-10-16   Hired
3             5      2015-10-17   Hired
```

Comment: You need a calendar table

Comment: @RyanVincent Hmmm, I didn't realise it would be little complicated to do this on MySQL side. I think it might be easier to use PHP to generate dates between `start_date` and `end_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table callender:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `callender` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

insert dates:

```
INSERT INTO `callender` (`date`) VALUES
('2015-10-03'),
('2015-10-04'),
('2015-10-05'),
('2015-10-06'),
('2015-10-07'),
('2015-10-08'),
('2015-10-09'),
('2015-10-10'),
('2015-10-11'),
('2015-10-12'),
('2015-10-13'),
('2015-10-14'),
('2015-10-15'),
('2015-10-16'),
('2015-10-17'),
('2015-10-18');
```

run query:

```
SELECT client_id, car_id, date, status
FROM booking
LEFT JOIN callender ON (date >= start_date
                        AND date<=end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `BETWEEN`-Keyword.

```
SELECT client_id, car_id, booked_date, status
FROM Your_table
WHERE booked_date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
```

Comment: ...sorry. I think I misunderstood your question. Forget about my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Or without callender table:

```
SELECT client_id, car_id, date, status
FROM booking
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT curdate() - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY AS Date
   FROM
     (SELECT 0 AS a
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 6
      UNION ALL SELECT 7
      UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
   CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 0 AS a
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 6
      UNION ALL SELECT 7
      UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
   CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 0 AS a
      UNION ALL SELECT 1
      UNION ALL SELECT 2
      UNION ALL SELECT 3
      UNION ALL SELECT 4
      UNION ALL SELECT 5
      UNION ALL SELECT 6
      UNION ALL SELECT 7
      UNION ALL SELECT 8
      UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c ) AS callender ON (date >= start_date
                                                  AND date<=end_date
```