# postgresql generating a list of dates between two dates fields

Tags: postgresql, date, date-range, dateinterval

I would like to get the list of dates from two fields: start and end.
I found a case here: [Show a list of dates between two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328857/show-a-list-of-dates-between-two-dates)

But I would like to have a better solution without going through an intermediary table.

Here is the initial table:

[image]

Here is the result I would like to have:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)

```
select t.id, t.name, t.g.dt::date as start_end
from the_table t
  cross join generate_series(t.date_start, t.date_end, interval '1 day') as g(dt)
order by t.id, g.dt;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. it works well. That's exactly what I wanted.
Thank.